# Change power plan to High Performance

Tags: powershell

How can I change my power plan on local computer to High performance and also change option: Turn off display after( I want to set never ).

I found all examples for remote computers.

Comment: I see many examples for `powercfg` on a local PC.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have a question about it; When I have Power Scheme GUID is always same for Windows 10?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by calling the `activate` method in the `Win32_PowerPlan` class:

```
$powerPlan = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_PowerPlan -Filter "ElementName = 'High Performance'"

$powerPlan.Activate()
```

This will change the power option to 'High Performance'.

To never turn off display use `powercfg` as wOxxOm mentioned:

```
powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 0
powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0
powercfg -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

Comment: I am getting error: Get-WmiObject : Missing an argument for parameter 'Class'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.

Comment: Are you running the command over two lines? I put the command on two lines to make the text more readable on SO. I've edited my answer - try again.

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expressio
At line:1 char:1
+ $powerPlan.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Are you calling the method before `$powerPlan` is initialized? The error states the method call is on line 1 of your script.. Initialize `$powerPlan` first.

Comment: Yes I did it like you said

Comment: Strange. It works for me on Windows 7 & Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I am using windows 10. Nevermind I'll try fix it.
Can you maybe know how to change registry value? There is path: Komputer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows And I want to set ErrorMode DWORD to value 2

Comment: @Defus FYI: If you're running Insider Preview builds then I think the `Win32_PowerPlan` class has been removed.

Comment: `$powerPlan.Activate()` fails on Windows 10 with **Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class "** It works fine on Windows Server. Amazingly it works on Windows 8.

Comment: It does not work on Windows 2019 Core or GUI neither. However, it works fine on Windows 2016 Core and GUI.

Answer (score 6):

```
powercfg.exe -SETACTIVE 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c
```

This would also work to set the power plan to high performance (tested on Win10 20H2 and newest Server 2019 [with GUI] build).

Comment: `powercfg /l` shows the different GUIDs: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e Balanced, 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c High performance, a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a Power saver

Comment: Worked on Win 11 22H2  (OS Build 22621.608)