# Using Invoke-CimMethod 'Activate' in order to activate a windows powerplan, instead I get Invalid Class what am I doing wrong?

Tags: powershell, invoke, cim

I followed the Scripting Guy instructions from Microsoft but even with this I still get the same error [Scripting Guy article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/27/use-powershell-and-wmi-or-cim-to-view-and-to-set-power-plans/)

here is my script:
`$p2=Get-CimInstance -N root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan -Filter "ElementName = 'Balanced'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $p2-MethodName Activate`

which results in:
`Invoke-CimMethod : This method is not implemented in any class 
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $p2 -MethodName Activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (Win32_PowerPlan...2-f694-41f0...):CimInstance) [Invoke-CimMethod], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041055,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.InvokeCimMethodCommand`

I cant seem to find answers I have looked in a few locations, I have seen people start to run into this a few months ago but I could not find an answer any advice would be appreciated

my end goal is to write a script where I import a powerplan and then activate it I have the import part working fine it just this last bit. $p contains my imported plan I used $p2 on a default plan for testing purposes.

cheers and thank you in advance for any advice you can offer

Comment: Just as added information I have also tried Get-WMIobject method found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921510/change-power-plan-to-high-performance but I got this error when trying that:   Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class "
At line:1 char:1
+ $p2.Activate()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException

Comment: I can do it via PowerCfg but if someone could let me know how to do it via CIM I would appreciate it as I would like to get better at using CIM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the `-Filter` you are using has a mistake. The `=` makes it an assignment, where you want to do a compare. Try `-Filter "ElementName -eq 'Balanced'"`. Also `$p2-MethodName` should be `$p2.MethodName` I gather.

Comment: Thank you, I took a break from this for a few days now I am back on it so lets get to it: making your changes to the `-filter` syntax actually generated a new error see my object is fine in the $p2 var up to the Invoke section Next I did try the $p2.methodName but it did not work either based on the Microsoft article the way I had it is how that method is to be called but hey I could be wrong I read around, a few others started having this issue as of a win 10 update back in may so this may not be fixable until microsoft solves the issue until then i guess im stuck with the PowerCFG method

Answer (score 0):

I found this code for changing the Power Schema.

```
Get-CimInstance -N root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan | select ElementName, IsActive | ft -a

$p = gwmi -NS root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan -Filter "ElementName ='Ultimate Performance'"

$p.Activate()


Get-CimInstance -N root\cimv2\power -Class win32_PowerPlan | select ElementName, IsActive | ft -a

pause
```

It works on most flavors of Windows O/S.  I get this error sometimes.

"Exception calling "Activate" : "This method is not implemented in any class " At line:1 char:1 + $p2.Activate() + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException –"

Comment: thank you for your answer I had ended up solving this exporting a collection of power-plans set the the way I want and then writing 2 power-shell scripts one to import the plan and a second using the GUID of the plan to set the plan as active, this method however requires a check to ensure you don't have duplicate power-profiles and to remove any duplicates so far its worked for over a year with no errors.